# No space before first section in framed box

Tags: sectioning, boxes, framed

I am looking for the correct way to lay out content in a framed box. In my opinion the space before the first section in a box looks odd in comparison to the same content at the start of a page. How can I remove the horizontal space before the first `section` in a framed box? In particular I am looking for a compositional solution, that is, I would like to use the same latex code no matter whether it is placed within a box or not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext


\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following, where a `minipage` is used rather than a `parbox` in the third instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext


\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext}}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

and which gives an output on the third page like:

[image: output]

Comment: oh and do note the `%` both in `\fbox{%` and at the end of the `minipage` where it necessary to type `\end{minipage}%` (or in fact `\end{minipage}}` if you prefer having the closing brace on the same line).

Comment: and I hope you are aware that neither with a `parbox` nor with a `minipage` this will behave nicely at a page break..

Comment: Ah, I see, so I was actually looking for a `minipage` rather than a `parbox`, thanks. I am aware that the box is not broken.

Answer (score 5):

The usage of package `tcolorbox` provides, correctly setup, very tight boxes around the text and other nice features

Since two sections are involved, the box should be breakable.

The options `left,top,right,bottom` and `boxsep` control the spacing between the box frame and the box content.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}%

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=0pt,right=0pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,width=\textwidth]%
\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}%


\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,width=\textwidth,colback={yellow},boxrule=4pt]%
\section{Title}
\blindtext

\section{Title}
\blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}%



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you forgot the `breakable` option in the specification of the `tcolorbox` - without it your solution has no advantage over the others.

Comment: @greyshade: Yes, I noticed, that I have forgotten it, but it is not your job to edit my answers. While you were editing my answer, I was just adding it ;-)

Comment: couldn't have known there was a bigger edit coming ;-) (and in the case of including `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}`, but then not using `breakable` I felt the author's intend was clear enough that an edit was warranted).

Comment: @greyshade: A comment is often sufficient. And I personally refrain from editing other users' answers, except in the `First Post` queue, for formatting issues.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was looking for a solution without using `tcolorbox`, I should probably have mentioned that.

Comment: @JanChristiansen: No problem at all...

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `framed` package. To illustrate what can be done with it,  I define a `frshaded` and a `frshaded*` environments, for which you can choose the colour of the frame and of the background. The difference is that the former environment has frame width equal to \linewidth, while the latter has frame built around a text of width \linewidth.

I adjusted the vertical spacing above first framed section with a `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`, compensated by `\vspace{\baselineskip}` before the frame. That can easily be incorporated in a `framedsections` environment.

Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{showframe, framed}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \setlength\FrameRule{0.8pt}
    \setlength\FrameSep{3pt}
    \renewcommand{\FrameHeightAdjust}{\baselineskip}

    \colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
    \colorlet{framecolor}{Red1}

    \newenvironment{frshaded}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
    \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
    {\endMakeFramed}

    \newenvironment{frshaded*}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
    {\endMakeFramed}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Title}
    \blindtext

    \section{Title}
    \blindtext
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \begin{frshaded*}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \section{Title}
    \blindtext

    \blindtext
    \section{Title}
    \blindtext
    \end{frshaded*}

    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \begin{frshaded}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \section{title}
    \blindtext

    \section{title}
    \blindtext
    \end{frshaded}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the example. I do not know whether the content in the box actually starts with a `section` or not. Therefore, I would like to avoid the use of an explicit `vspace` with a negative amount. Can I avoid this approach without using a `minipage`?