# Creating self notes while preparing a manuscript (Yellow block of text in between the normal text)

Tags: thesis, notes, report

I am writing a pretty long report (more than 100 pages) and at times I need to keep track of several things to do in a particular page, or section, or chapter. What I currently do is that I keep a separate doc file and write notes on to it. For eg, when I am writing a section in my manuscript, I parallely make a entry of notes on another text file on how I can improve this section and so on. I would like this on my main manuscript itself. I don't mind if it creates problems for my page counting. Is there a package for this?

If possible, I would like it as a bordered yellow box with my ideas in it between the normal text

EDIT: I figured out how to do this with todo package and it all seems nice!!. I am not sure now what I will do with this question. I leave it to the moderators to delete it.

Comment: would something like the suggestions in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195786/no-space-before-first-section-in-framed-box/195787) help?

Comment: You need a reminder *to do* something? Ever heard of package `todonotes`?